# Why std::queue doesn't implement insert() while std::deque does?

Tags: c++, c++11, queue, deque

I was reading [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) and I was wondering why there is no method to efficiently insert multiple elements with a single operation, while [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) offers [`std::deque::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/insert)?

Comment: A `queue` has a limited interface for cases where you *don't want to* use the full power of a `deque`. It's an abstraction.

Comment: @BoPersson I don't really understand it. Why shouldn't I want to use the super sayan power of `deque`? Maybe there are some differences in performance terms between these two data structures?

Comment: @justHelloWorld `std::queue` is high level container with an underlying container that might or might not efficiently implement insert, so it's not really a data structure with known performance as such.

Comment: @justHello - Sometimes it is better *not* to use the biggest tools, like not using a chain saw to cut a small stick. If you use a smaller interface you also limit the number of errors possible, and that can make it easier to reason about the code. `std::queue` will not let anyone "cut the queue" and enter the queue in the middle, which might be a limitation you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert allows insertion into an arbitrary position into the structure.

`std::queue` is an abstract interface for a FIFO structure. You can only add things to the end. The underlying structure doesn't necessarily have an efficient way to insert into arbitrary position (consider `std::vector` for example). Therefore `std::queue` has no general insert member function.

Since the general insertion function requires the iterator position argument, the multiple-insert is provided as a convenience, so that you don't have to keep track of the next iterator position. The push back doesn't have need for this because no iterator tracking is needed and a trivial loop is sufficient.

Comment: This a good answer, now I understand it, I didn't thought the obvious: with `insert` you can insert elements wherever you want in the queue, while I was thinking about "only at the top of the queue". Btw, they could have implemented such a method (maybe with some kind of optimizations instead of a naive for `push` loops.

Comment: @justHelloWorld they could have and I don't think it would have been a terribly bad idea either. However, the performance gain would probably be marginal in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

`std::queue` is an adapter that is *intended* to be limited to push/pop interfaces. It will not expose `insert` even if `std::vector` is an underlying implementation.

There are no particular performance reasons, merely a design approach: if you *feel* that your container is a queue, you just do not expose interfaces you don't need.